# Issue with overlapping features in PostgreSQL database st_difference not working

Tags: postgis, clip, overlapping-features

I am working on a problem in a postgreSQL database with the Postgis extension.  My issue is that I have a bunch of polygons in a table and they have some overlap.  These are US census blocks.  Not sure why this is.  So I have been reading what to do and getting some issue.  For the application to work everything needs to be multi_polygons in geography format.

[image]

So I need to get this overlap to go away and have the two census blocks butt up to each other.  I have been reading some similar issues and cannot get what they did to work when using st_difference.  Can you compare polygons in the same table with st_difference to remove the overlap area?  I need one of the polygons to take it and the other to not.  Similar to clip in ArcMap/Qgis.  But I cannot use those programs and have to do it all in the database.  If not what would be a good way to do this in Postgis.

Here is what I have been trying and not succeeding with.

```
update public.census_blocks
set shape_trimmed = st_multi(st_difference(shape_trimmed::geometry,   
shape_trimmed::geometry))::geography
where st_intersects(shape_trimmed, shape_trimmed) and     
census_blocks.service_area_id = 4017;
```

Comment: could you explain some more what the picture shows, I can't see any overlap in it

Comment: The area where the road is if you zoom in further actually shows where the census block polygons overlap.  You can see a light black line and that goes to the polygon above the road and the darker line was the polygon that i selected.  What I need to do is clip that area where the road is from one of the polygons and not the other so no more overlap.